# How can I write a bash script to calculate an integral?

Tags: bash, sum, integral

I want to write a bash script. The script have to read a file containing two columns. It has to read the first row of the first column (let's say x1). Then it has to read the second row (let's say v2) and the first row (let's say v1) of the second column. Then it has to calculate the value x1-y1 where y1=v2-v1. All this for each row of the first column till the end of the file and return all values to an output.

For my personal and basic experience the real difficulty is to call the variables as I described. As written in the title the operation is to evaluate an integral.

If you have any suggestion like write the same script with python because easier It will be fine for me.

I really thank you all.

UPDATE
I tried with Python. I have some difficulties to obtain an iteration script. This is what I have:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

for i in range(0, 99):
xvals=np.loadtxt("pos{}.txt".format(i), float)
yvals=np.loadtxt("forc{}.txt".format(i), float)

if (len(xvals) != len(yvals)):
print ("Error bla bla")
sys.exit()

integr = 0

for i in range (1, len(xvals), 1):
integr = integr + yvals[i]*(xvals[i] - xvals[i-1])

integr=np.savetxt("work{}.txt".format(i), integr.reshape(1,), fmt='%1.5f')
```

Thank you all again.

Comment: Can you show a sample input? Also, what have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: I presume you are aware that `bash` on its own cannot deal with floating point, i.e. non-integer, values...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at bash arrays, so here is an example to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Declare two arrays
declare -a x
declare -a y

# Read two values from each line of input file and append to arrays "x" and "y"
while read c1 c2 ; do
   x+=($c1)
   y+=($c2)
   echo "read c1=$c1 and c2=$c2"
   # Demonstrate some maths - a simple difference
   ((diff=c2-c1))
   echo "difference: $diff"
done < file.txt

# Print a couple of elements to see how to access them
echo "x[0]=${x[0]}"
echo "y[2]=${y[2]}"
```

If I use this as `file.txt`:

```
10 20
11 21
12 22
```

I get this:

```
read c1=10 and c2=20
difference: 10
read c1=11 and c2=21
difference: 10
read c1=12 and c2=22
difference: 10
x[0]=10
y[2]=22
```

Hopefully that is enough to get you started. As I mentioned in the comments, `bash` cannot do floating point maths, so if your data are floating point, you will probably need to use `awk` or `Python`.